# How to hide a fixed position sidemenu via shrinking width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I've got a side menu with table of contents on my pages. I want it to be expandable/collapsible. I've got it sort of working, the only problem is the animation doesn't look right because when I shrink the width of the side menu, the text of the links can be seen shrinking as well. I've tried several version of overflow and setting minimum widths and toggles. But the result is always either this awkward shrinking, or it doesn't hide it at all and it just sits outside the main container div.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DR2Y2/15/

You can't really see it in action unless you do the fullscreen: http://jsfiddle.net/DR2Y2/15/embedded/result/

I think there is something wrong with my css, but perhaps there is better jQuery to write to achieve the desired effect. My Jquery looks like this:

```
$("#table-of-contents-link").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $rightcolumn = $("#right-column");
        var $leftcolumn = $("#left-column");
        var $toc = $(".table-of-contents");
        if ($rightcolumn.width() == 1) {

            $rightcolumn.animate({
                width: "22%",
            }, 1500 );
            $leftcolumn.animate({
                width: "71%",
            }, 1500);
            //$toc.show();
        }else {
            $rightcolumn.animate({
                width: "1",
            }, 1500);
            $leftcolumn.animate({
                width: "95%",
            }, 1500);
            //$toc.hide();
        }
```

});

I basically just want the elements of right-column to shrink away into the edge of the main container. It almost works except the awkward link text effect.

**EDIT** I've updated my fiddle to show more what I mean. I have this contained in a container that is set to 90% width. I want the right column contents to disappear into the edge of that container, not the edge of the screen.

Comment: you are missing the `event` in `$("#table-of-contents-link").click(function () {`

Comment: The effect you're after is called off-canvas, demo here: http://zurb.com/playground/projects/off-canvas/offcanvas-4.html, More info here: http://zurb.com/playground/off-canvas-layouts

Comment: @SamBattat I don't know what you mean.

Comment: @Varinder I'd rather not use a whole extra plugin when I have it almost working myself. Also from the page it looks like it takes it off the entire screen, which I can do. I'm not trying to have it animate to be removed off screen, but shrink to nothing on the border of my container.

Comment: Why are you trying to shrink it? You should translate it or animate it with margin. That will look more convincing.

Comment: @LokeshSuthar Like I said, perhaps there is another way to write the jquery. Can you give an example of what you mean? I do want the animation to be like so though. The contents button is always displayed, and the right-column dissappears into the edge of the #main container.

Comment: Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/embLD/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2** with jQuery animation: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/embLD/7/

**Edit**
On a second thought, you wouldnt need transition on `width` property, `transform` will do the job just fine.

updated fiddle with 90% wide content area: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/embLD/5/

---

You could leverage transitions, although not sure if its a good idea to add transitions on `padding` and `width` properties.

I've slightly tweaked the markup to achevie floating-ish effect. I.e when the sidebar is shrinking - content flows to fill the remaining space.

**fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/embLD/3/

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="table-of-contents-link">Toggle TOC</a>
<div id="main">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            ..content..
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="toc-wrapper">
        <div class="fixed table-of-contents" style="border-top: 1px solid #577ec5; width: inherit;">
            <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
            <ul style="margin-left: 3px;">
                ..content..
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#main {
   overflow:hidden; /*clearfix*/
}

.content-wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}

.content {
    padding-right:220px; /* width of toc (200px) + gutter (20px) */
    transition:padding-right .3s ease;
}

.toc-wrapper {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:-200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition:width .3s ease;
}

.toc-wrapper a {
    display:block;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

.hide-toc .content {
    padding-right:0;
}

.hide-toc .toc-wrapper {
    width:0;
}
```

JS

```
var $page = $("#main");
var $tocLink = $("#table-of-contents-link");

$tocLink.on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $page.toggleClass("hide-toc");
});
```

Comment: This still has the same problem. You can see as the content shrinks. The Lorem Ipsum header in the right column, goes from taking up one line, to taking up two lines, before it disappears. The same happens to the links that have longer text. Thus making the animation look less than ideal.

Comment: Oh true sorry man, i was being lazy. That can be fixed by using a combination of ```white-space```, ```overflow``` and ```text-overflow``` properties. updated my fiddle. and adding it here just in case: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/embLD/3/ -cheers

Comment: The 5 version doesn't work on my screen. The TOC just stays in place. Though I have been taking your solution and trying to get it to work, but can't quite get it yet. I can't use transition CSS property because IE doesn't support it except in v10, but so far your solution has gotten me the closest.

Comment: Because TOC was not in the flow. you can move it around in your markup to get its positioning right. Updated my answer with another fiddle, now using jquery animation for browser support: http://jsfiddle.net/Varinder/embLD/7/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, to be honest I cannot see that much of jQuery for a simple task. Here is what I came up with in 5 mins.

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/oraeE)**

```
<div class="sidebar active"></div>
<div class="content">
  <button id="btn">click me</button>
</div>
```

---

```
.sidebar{
  position:fixed;
  left:-200px;
  top:0;
  width:200px;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:red;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar.active{
  left:0;
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:blue;
}

#btn{
  margin-left:300px;
}
```

---

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    $('.sidebar').toggleClass('active');
});
```

---

**EDIT**

OP requested to have a sidebar inside a container. here is my updated code.

```
.parent{
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.sidebar{
  margin-left:-200px;
  top:0;
  float:left;
  width:200px;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:red;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.sidebar.active{

  margin-left:0px;
}
.content{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I admit I am not great at jQuery so I use too many lines to basic stuff. There is one issue with your solution though which makes it not as simple. I want it to fade into the edge of my main container, not the edge of the screen. I've updated my fiddle to show that more clearly: http://jsfiddle.net/DR2Y2/15/embedded/result/ The #main container is only 90% width of the whole page. Also the webkite-transition command makes the animation not work in IE.

Comment: Not a problem. You can add `overflow-x:hidden` to a parent container. Let me update my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a wrapper surrounding the menu button and the menu itself, absolutely positioned over the main left-column. The widths are all handled by CSS, as there's no need to add to the page load with extra jQuery when CSS already has it covered.

I had to make some tweaks to the HTML to get this working.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DR2Y2/2/)

```
<div id="main">
   <div class="menu-wrapper">
      <div class="toc-button-column">
          <a href="#" id="table-of-contents-link">TOC</a>
     </div>
     <div id="right-column">
         <div class="table-of-contents" style="border-top: 1px solid #577ec5;">
             <div style="padding-left: 15px;">
                <h3>Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                <ul style="margin-left: 3px;">
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#tabs-1">Section 1</a></li>
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#tabs-2">Section 2 Text</a></li>
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#tabs-3">Section 3 Example</a></li>
                    <li><a class="scroll" href="#tabs-4">Section 4</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div><!-- End right column -->
</div> <!-- End Main -->

<div id="left-column">
    <h2 id="tabs-1">Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>The cyanide ion CN- is highly toxic bLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
     </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- End Main -->
```

then the jQuery:

```
    $("#table-of-contents-link").click(function () {
         var rightColumn = $("#right-column"),
         wrapper = $(".menu-wrapper"); 

         rightColumn.toggle("slide, left");
         wrapper.css('width', 'auto');
});
```

I'd be inclined to go with Varinder's solution, as simply toggling a class will use less juice than running animations.

If this code is intended for devices, the CSS will update faster than the jQuery code will run. Only very modern phones can play animations smoothly.

Think of them like animated GIFs. They play super-fast when you create them, but then the browser plays them in slo-mo.

Comment: This doesn't work due to other div and styles being applied to on the page. There is a lot going on in the page. So whatever occurs must be contained in the #main div. Both the content and sidebar table of contents list must be inside it.